# Method collision when implementing two interfaces in java, when return value is typed

Tags: java, generics, interface, extends

I want to implement 2 interfaces

```
interface Bar { 
  List<Beers> getDrinks();
}

interface Fridge {
   List<Soda> getDrinks();
}
```

I want to implement a class that satisfies both..

```
class Backyard<T extends Beer, Soda> implements Bar, Fridge {
    List<T> getDrinks() { return null; } 
}
```

The problem is when I specify  as the List type, it says im attempting to return incompatible types. Is this possible to do in Java 7?

If i change my example to have getDrinks() to just return Beer or Soda, then I can return T without issue from my Backyard class.

Note; my example is a bit contrived; what im doing in reality is trying to wrap 2 versions of an API (which i dont have control over). For my particular use case, its a bit frustrating because I will be returning null or throwing unsupported operation exceptions since i only need to combine for a limited set of functionality for my use case.

Comment: No. `List<Beers>` and `List<Soda>` are incompatible, so there is nothing (no type) you can return that is compatible with both at the same time.

Comment: Do you really need the same class to implement both interfaces or could you apply some sort of composition/delegation internally?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Or proxy/adapter.

Comment: Unfortunately im a bit hamstrung by the APIs (which are 3rd party); Thanks for the feedback and I will need to revisit how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Keep in mind that anyone having a reference of type `Bar` can say `bar.getDrinks().add(new ActualBeerType());` without having to fulfill the constraint that it has to be a subtype of `Soda`. So when `bar` actually refers to a `Backyard` instance, you would have a heap pollution if that was allowed. It is only possible if the declaration were `interface Bar { List<? extends Beers> getDrinks(); }` and `interface Fridge { List<? extends Soda> getDrinks(); }` as then, no one could insert incompatible objects. Then, `Backyard` would work if you change it to `class Backyard<T extends Beer & Soda>`

Comment: @Holger thanks - great points. My issue is i don't control the code for `Bar` or `Fridge` so i cant change their method signatures. That being said, definitely great info for others that might own the entire code set.